# How do you select Slicers from VBA using array? (Excel 2016) Goal: Get slicer selection, clear slicers, run macro, re-select slicers

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, slicers

I have two slicers on Sheet1 (Status1&Server). I want to store the selected elements, reset the slicers, and select them again after running a sort macro. Here's what I have:

```
    Option Explicit

Sub GetSlicerNCSTatusSel()
    Dim MyArrStatus() As Variant
    Dim MyArrServer() As Variant

    
    
    MyArrStatus = ArrayListOfSelectedAndVisibleSlicerItems("Slicer_Status1")
    MyArrServer = ArrayListOfSelectedAndVisibleSlicerItems("Slicer_Server")
    
    
    Dim slcr As SlicerCache
    Dim slc  As Slicer
    
    Dim element As Variant
    
     
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     
    For Each slcr In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
        For Each slc In slcr.Slicers
            If slc.Shape.Parent Is ActiveSheet Then
                slcr.ClearManualFilter
                
                
                Exit For
            End If
        Next slc
    Next slcr
    
srtnc
  
    For Each element In MyArrStatus
        ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Status1").SlicerItems(element).Selected = True
    Next element



    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub



Public Function ArrayListOfSelectedAndVisibleSlicerItems(MySlicerName As String) As Variant


    Dim ShortList() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer: i = 0 'for iterate

    Dim sC As SlicerCache
    Dim sI As SlicerItem 'for iterate

    Set sC = ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(MySlicerName)
    For Each sI In sC.SlicerItems
        If sI.Selected = True And sI.HasData = True Then 'Here is the condition!!!
                'Debug.Print sI.Name
            ReDim Preserve ShortList(i)
            ShortList(i) = sI.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next sI
    ArrayListOfSelectedAndVisibleSlicerItems = ShortList
End Function
```

I think the problem is somewhere in the following portion. I just have no idea what I'm doing wrong as I am a bit of a VBA newb.

```
    For Each element In MyArrStatus
        ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Status1").SlicerItems(element).Selected = True
    Next element
```